# What is the best practice when displaying data from more than one table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I have three tables,  '**sessions**', **'classes'** and '**schedules**' which they are connected each other.

> sessions: id, name, descr
>
> classes: id, session_id, name
>
> schedules: class_id, session_id, date

A class belongs to a session, while the schedules is a N:M relations which gives the opportunity to have particular date for each session within a single class.

My problem comes when I have to display these information, I have a function which displays all Sessions:

```
$sessions = Session::all();
```

and I have another function which displays the date of a specific class and a specific session  as below:

```
$result = Schedule:where('class_id','=',$classId)->where('session_id','=',$essionId)->first();
```

So let say I have 30 sessions for a single class, when it comes to my front-end app which is written in AngularJS I dont know how to handle the displaying here using the ng-repeat iterating thru all sessions and then make another call withing the ng-repeat iteration to call the schedule to display the date of the session, this is not a good practice I guess in AngularJS.

Could anyone tell me what would be the best option for me to handle this problem? Shall I have to modify the back-end? like edit the Session:all(); query to include also the Schedule table? or what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

1. I supposed you have already config your relations in models, if not look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)
2. As for me, I use [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) to customize display data. Also there is convenient method called [Available includes](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/)
   So you can request your data like `/sessions/?include=classes` and get output

`{data: [{
     session_id: 1,
     some: "data",
     classes:[{
         class_id: 11,
         some: "class_data"
     }]
 }]}`

Answer (score 0):

I would "eager load" the data, so you can access all the object's parents through the object you loaded. This way you can fill your table rows one by one by just iterating over 1 object.

There is [excellent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) about eager loading at the Laravel website, so I suggest you start there

Comment: I am already doing this: public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule', 'schedules', 'session_id', 'id');
    }
 and in ctrl I have this: $sessions = Session::with('schedule')->get(); but I am getting an error Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'schedules' (SQL: select `schedules`.*, `schedules`.`session_id` as `pivot_session_id`, `schedules`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `schedules` inner join `schedules` on `schedules`.`id` = `schedules`.`id` where `schedules`.`session_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))